# Ruby - how to pass a single argument to a method with long list of arguments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way to pass a single argument to a ruby function that has only optional parameters?

For instance, I want to pass ignoreAlreadyCrawled = true in the method below, and use the default parameter values for everything else. But since it's the last parameter, I have to do call crawl(nil, nil, nil, false, nil, false, nil, false, [], true), which is verbose, and ugly.

Method:

```
def crawl(url = nil, proxy = nil, userAgent = nil, post = false, postData = nil, image = false, imageFilename = nil, forceNoUserAgent = false, ignoreSubDomains = [], ignoreAlreadyCrawled = false)   
        #..logic here
    end
```

Comment: Which version of ruby are you using?  You could look into [keyword arguments](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/ruby-2-keyword-arguments) if using ruby 2

Comment: Ruby 2.1.2 is my version

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is possible for ruby >= 2.0 with keyword arguments. In that case, you have to modify the method signature as follows (basically change `=` to `:`):

```
def crawl(url: nil, proxy: nil, userAgent: nil, post: false, postData: nil, image: false, imageFilename: nil, forceNoUserAgent: false, ignoreSubDomains: [], ignoreAlreadyCrawled: false)   
    #..logic here
end
```

And it will work as expected:

```
crawl(ignoreAlreadyCrawled: true)
```

Please see article for more examples: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/ruby-2-keyword-arguments

Comment: If I modify the method signature, can I still call it the old way IE. crawl(someargument) ? or do I always need to specify the keyword?

Comment: I'm afraid, if you change your method to use keyword arguments, you have to stick to them.

Answer (score 1):

When you have more than two or three arguments, the preferred pattern is to use a Hash of options instead.

I would redefine this method as follows: this is similar to Pawel's but more readable, i think:

```
def crawl(options={})
  defaults = { url: nil, 
               proxy: nil, 
               userAgent: nil, 
               post: false, 
               postData: nil, 
               image: false, 
               imageFilename: nil, 
               forceNoUserAgent: false, 
               ignoreSubDomains: [], 
               ignoreAlreadyCrawled: false
             }
    options = defaults.merge(options)
    #..logic here

end
```

You could omit from defaults all options that have `nil` as their default, as an undefined option will come out as nil anyway.  But, having them there acts as documentation for which options **can** be passed.

Comment: I'd not that this is the preferred method in Ruby versions prior to 2.0. Otherwise, I'd prefer the use of keyword arguments like Pawel suggested.